# xUnit Tests give message failing to load extensions in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2022, xunit

I added an xUnit project to my solution and started writing tests for my project.
I wrote 3 tests and everything seemed to be working fine.  They were red when something was wrong and would go green as I fixed them.

The first test I wrote for an extension method where I convert an IQueryable to an IQueryable of another type.  Basically converting the IQueryable from a simple object to a DTO object.

I used an extension to mock called MockQueryable.Mock that makes it easier to work with DbSets and IQueryables in testing.
I didn't see any problems in Test Explorer.  It was going well.

I wrote two more tests for a class called ApiResult which at this point takes in three parameters; an IQueryable datasource,  pageIndex, pageSize and then returns a Five properties; Data and four properties of paging info for the front end.

Then I wrote the fourth test for the controller itself (in a Web API project) and then Visual Studio and Test Explorer started acting very weird.

Once I added in that last test and tried to run all tests, it would hang forever and I would have to kill the vstesthost.exe in Task Manager.

When I first create the xUnit project it adds xunit nuget package version 2.4.2.

This is the error I started getting in Test Explorer.  I have to do a print screen real quick to catch this as it goes through several messages such as building, discovering and so forth.

xUnit 2.4.2
Failed to load extensions for xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll
path:
c:\Users\username.nuget\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.4.5\build\netcoreapp3.1

[image]

The message in the screen shot says to use \diag for more information but I don't know how or where to do this.  On the command line?  Like: dotnet test \diag?

Then I upgraded the xunit package to the latest version.  2.6.2.

And now it is failing to load another package from a different location.

xUnit 2.6.2
Failed to load extensions for xunit.runner.visualstudio.uwp.testadapter.dll
c:\Users\username.nuget\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.4.5\build\uap10.0.16299

[image]

I can actually run one or two tests at a time and although I see this message flicker by the tests will run and pass.  But when I click run all it just hangs and I get these crazy tilde '~' characters for the message.

[image]

Only when I try to run all the tests at once does it just hang and freeze and give me tilde chars.  But even on the single test runs if it passes I want to get rid of this fail to load error.

Running `dotnet test` from the command line also gives a weird outcome.
Actually, maybe the command line is working.
I just ran it again.
And it says:
Passed! - Failed: 0, Passed: 4, Skipped 0.

[image]

So it did find and run all my tests.
This problem must be strictly Test Explorer and xUnit integration within Visual Studio 2022.

This would be a lot of code for me to try to put here.
I am going to put on github:
https://github.com/smiller7812/FredsCarsFullStackAngularMod26.git

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the complete answer.  But at least I can run all tests at once from Test Explorer now.

I just upgraded the xunit.runner.visualstudio package to 2.5.4 and I was able to run all the tests at once from Test Explorer without it hanging.

Although those failed to load extension messages still fly by.  That's why I note I don't know if this is the complete answer.

But at least it is usable now.